# horizontal ul menu not displaying correctly in IE - Getting Squashed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with a horizontal UL menu im trying to make see screenshots...

In Chrome it works perfectly fine:
[image]

Where as in IE-8 it looks like this:
[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="navbar-top">
    <ul class="horizontal-menu">                    
        <li><a href="google"> Google </a> </li>
        <li><a href="google"> Google </a> </li>
        <li><a href="google"> Google </a> </li>
        <li><a href="google"> Google </a> </li>
        <li><a href="google"> Google </a> </li>
    </ul>           

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.horizontal-menu {
    width: 440px;
}

.horizontal-menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Any clues guys?

Really baffling me now :p cheers

Nick

Comment: increase width or decrease padding-left then check ie8

Comment: please see the link  http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/WmPxG/ working fine in ie8

Comment: Thanks guys, would it be worth pasting up the whole pages html so you can check all the sizes? I have a few different containers you see throughout the page at different fixed widths.

Comment: Ahhh just an update... I reduced the padding to 20px now they all sit in line but how would I center them too the nav bar?

http://i121.photobucket.com/albums/o230/chapster5/3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.horizontal-menu { white-space: nowrap }
```

Will force the `li`-elements to stay in one line.

This should fix the unexpected linebreak, if you want to have the paddings that way.

```
* { margin:0; padding: 0 }
```

Could fix several browser inconsistency. Or integrate a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

---

To center the navigation across all browsers, you can remove the width from `.horizontal-menu` and set it `display: inline` and center it via `margin: 0 auto`:

```
.horizontal-menu {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Explanation:
margin: **0** auto; >> top/bottom margin
margin: 0 **auto**; >> left/right margin.

Comment: Many thanks for that mate! Worked like a dream let me keep my padding how ever now its a case of trying to center the gits throughout all the browsers they look centered in Chrome

Comment: @NicholasChappell Fixed it and edited my post. If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Your a legend, what exactly does display: inline do? (I know its probably exactly what it says on the tin

Comment: `ul`-elements are block elements by default. That means, this element will take the full available width of its parent element, if you don't set a width via CSS. `display: inline` converts it to a inline element, so the width of it will be the width of its elements inside. So I can center it like text: [differencies between inline/block-elements](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-distinctions-between-inline-and-block-html-elements/6094821)

Comment: Ahhh makes sense :) Thank you! now with your Example above with the 

* { margin:0; padding: 0 }

How do I override this in my style for say the nav bar? I want to pad them down to the center of the element but when I add padding it doesnt move ive even put !important on the padding line before the closure symbol(;) and still no luck :(

Comment: They wont center in IE8 to the vertical center of the nav bar :/ Ive padded the main background container and it centers it in Chrome but IE8 It pushed the links to the bottom of the nav bar?

Comment: Ok, what you can do to fix this problem is, absolute positioning the `ul` with a width, then `left: 50%` and a left negative margin.